# Who are the blond boys in Marvel Meow Infinity Comic #10?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification

Marvel Meow is all about cat hijinx, and the *Infinity* run stars Loki as a cat starting around the middle of the 12-issue run. In #10, there's something going on in the park with Ogeode (they brawl, mayhem, Dr. Strange saves the day...).

And then come two panels that appear rather interesting to me: two boys say "Uncle Loki?" to the clearly Loki white cat and cat-Loki denies it like the liar he is. But... I can't figure out who the two are meant to be... who are they?

[image: the aforementioned panels]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Marvel.com](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/98589/marvel_meow_infinity_comic_2022_10), that issue is set in [Strange Academy](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/28177/strange_academy_2020_-_present)...

> Cat Loki spreads mischief and mayhem amongst the students of Strange Academy!

... which presumably makes those boys two of the students at Strange Academy. The most obvious candidates are [Iric Brorson](https://www.marvel.com/characters/iric) and his twin brother, [Alvi](https://www.marvel.com/characters/alvi), sons of [Bror](https://mightythor.fandom.com/wiki/Bror_(Earth-616)) and the [Enchantress](https://www.marvel.com/characters/enchantress-amora).

> IRIC BRORSON: My name is Iric of Asgard, and this handsome devil beside me is my brother, Alvi.
>
> [image: Strange Academy #1, page 13.]
>
> <sub>*[Strange Academy #1](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/79798/strange_academy_2020_1)* (May, 2020)</sub>

Comment: I'm not sure why "presumably" is required here.

Comment: They aren't actually named in the issue itself, or in the official solicit for the issue, so I'm making a presumption as to who they are (albeit, one I'm pretty confident about).

Comment: Loki was also a good friend of the two in asgard it seems, explaining them calling him Uncle